# String formatting floats with %x.yf

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading through *Natural Language Processing With Python* and I've come across:

```
count, total = 3205, 9375
"accuracy for %d words: %2.4f%%" % (total, 100 * count / total)
```

I've seen the `%.4f`but never with an integer in front of the decimal point. Playing around with it the following all print the same thing (`34.1867`):

```
print('%.4f' %(100*count/total))
print('%0.4f' %(100*count/total))
print('%1.4f' %(100*count/total))
print('%2.4f' %(100*count/total))
```

etcetera. What does the value in front of the decimal do?

Comment: It means at least 2 numbers before the decimal place, which 34 already has - try it with a value less than 10, or make the number in the template larger than 2. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#number_padding

Comment: @jonrsharpe it appears the padding is based on the total characters i.e the numbers both before and after the decimal place as well as the decimal point itself. So `%7.4f` still produces `34.1867` but `%8.4f` produces ` 34.1867`.

Comment: Per the docs it's the "minimal field width" for the whole number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number specifies the [minimum field width](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), i.e. the minimum length of the complete output.

For example, to force the output to have at least 6 characters with 2 after the decimal point you do:

```
'%06.2f' % (3.141592653589793,)
```

Output:

```
003.14
```